# Parsing a JSON from Python Dataframe to React FE

Tags: python, reactjs, json, pandas, frontend

I am having a super hard time parsing a Pandas Dataframe from the backend to a React front end

I create the following in my python BE:

```
dataB = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(date)):
        dataB[i]=pd.Series({'fileName': name_[i], 'content': content[i], 'date': date[i]})
        
    return dataB
```

I then send it through a GET method in my flask Api

```
@app.route('/app4', methods=['GET'])
def ListPrint3():
    df = dataFrameFromPythonBE
    df1 = df.to_json() 
    return df1
```

this yields the following (simplified for the sake of brevity) when I console.log it in my display component using the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/app4').then(
            response=> {
                if (response.ok){
                    return response.json()
                }
            }
        ).then(data => console.log(data))
    },[])

#Yields the DataFrame below

1: {fileName: 'C.V. Alice Scotti. - Copia.Pdf', content: `dausdhiauhdiaushd`, date: 1483999986000}
2: {fileName: 'C.V. Alice Scotti..Pdf', content: `suhdaiudhaiudiauhdaiushd `, date: 1483999986000}
3: {fileName: 'Cv Alice Palladino-Signed - Copia - Copia.Pdf', content: `asdadfgaread`,date:...etc
```

I am trying to display it in my React front end but I'm having a very hard time parsing it and/or displaying it in a < li > that loops, as the Pandas Dataframe won't always be the same length

I don't know whether I should structure it differently or not. Whenever I try to parse it by using, say, data.fileName, data.content etc it doesn't seem to return anything.

How would you guys go about this?

PS
I also tried to package the Dataframe so:

```
{fileName: {…}, content: {…}, date: {…}}
content: {0: `aisjaoifjeifjaoifjaoiwfjawif', 1:'asfasfafafafasfassdtdhwaeefd', 2 .....etc}
date: {0: 1483999986000, 1: 1483999986000, 2: 1483999986000 .....etc}
fileName: {0: 'C.V. Alice Scotti. - Copia - Copia.Pdf', 1: 'C.V. Alice Scotti. -.....etc }
```

This is obviously structured different so the parsing should be different too I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this for whomever might be interested

The issue was that when I turned the dataframe into Json using .to_json() I didn't use the "orient" option for it

```
@app.route('/app4', methods=['GET'])
def ListPrint3():
    df = dataFrameFromPythonBE
    df1 = df.to_json(orient='records') 
    return df1
```

This made it very much easier to slice it using df.fileName, df.content etc. when displaying it